# ANT Deployment from SVN Repo to Sandbox

Tags: deployment, ant, subversion, ant-script

I have done deployment using ANT and I don't see much challenge in doing that. I would like know whether it is possible to 1. **Retrieve components from Salesforce org hosted on SVN Repo** and 2. Deploy those components to another org. First part is where I'm stuck. I have gone through this [article](http://www.aliaspooryorik.com/blog/index.cfm/e/posts.details/post/automated-deployment-of-svn-revisions-with-ant-315) but there is no reference to Salesforce in it. I have started using ANT only after having learnt Salesforce so I do not know how it works with other languages/ platforms.

If you have worked on building such scripts, please guide me. Any reference article or even pseudo code of what needs to be done in build.xml or build.properties would be a great help.

**EDIT:**

Suppose I have installed ANT where SVN is hosted. In this case I have all metadata locally available. So in the retrieveUnpackaged command instead of using salesforce credential to login to the org and retrieve components I want to copy the subset of data (described in package.xml) from overall data to the retrieveUnpackaged folder. Is it achievable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you are after continuous integration .... This can be done with some free tools like Jenkins. In Jenkins you can write multiple ant and SVN commands. You can use combination of those to retrieve, deploy, pull and push your metadata.

Comment: Ultimate goal is Continuous Integration using Jenkins. However, as of now we do not have Jenkins in place. We are planning to implement Jenkins in about month or so. Can this be done without Jenkins?

Comment: @Aryansh04 I suggest you go straight to Jenkins. It's available as a service (e.g. https://www.cloudbees.com/products/jenkins-cloud) or is not hard to setup locally. It makes the SVN part very easy.

Comment: I have worked with several customers who had challenges. They wanted to use version control like GIT and SVN. However, an pre-built solution like Flosum solves this need very well. You won't have to write scripts. It offers the complete solution including version control and Continuous Integration out of the box.